# Angular input currency directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a custom input directive for currency values, with two buttons on its side to increment and decrement value.

Right now it's working, but when the user inputs some text the number is not formatted. What am I doing wrong?

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/x8L74g75/3/

And this is the custom directive:

```
app.directive('inputMoney', ['$locale', '$filter', function ($locale, $filter) {
    var numberFilter = $filter('number');

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            ngDisabled: '=?',
            min: '=?',
            max: '=?'
        },
        require: 'ngModel',
        template: '<button type="button" class="increment" ng-click="increment(-10)" ng-disabled="ngDisabled">–</button>' +
            '<input type="tel" ng-model="ngModelCtrl.$viewValue" ng-disabled="ngDisabled" min="min" max="max" autofocus required autocomplete="off">' +
            '<button type="button" class="increment" ng-click="increment(10)" ng-disabled="ngDisabled">+</button>',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attr, ngModel) {
            var $input = $element.find('input');
            $scope.ngModelCtrl = ngModel;

            ngModel.$parsers.push(function inputMoneyParser(value) {
                var rawNumber = value + '';

                while (rawNumber.indexOf($locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.GROUP_SEP) >= 0) {
                    rawNumber = rawNumber.replace($locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.GROUP_SEP, '');
                }

                return parseInt(rawNumber);
            });
            $scope.$watch('ngModelCtrl.$viewValue', ngModel.$setViewValue);

            //Group separator
            ngModel.$formatters.push(function inputMoneyFormatter(value) {
                return numberFilter(value);
            });

            //Validators
            ngModel.$validators.value = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                return !isNaN(modelValue) && isFinite(modelValue);
            };
            ngModel.$validators.min = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                return angular.isUndefined($scope.min) ? true : modelValue >= $scope.min;
            };
            ngModel.$validators.max = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                return angular.isUndefined($scope.max) ? true : modelValue <= $scope.max;
            };
            $scope.$watch('ngModelCtrl.$valid', function (isValid) {
                $input.toggleClass('ng-invalid ng-dirty', !isValid);
            });

            //Only allow numbers and group separator input
            $input.on('keypress', function inputMoneyKeyPress(e) {
                var charCode = angular.isUndefined(e.which) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
                var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

                if (charStr && charStr != $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.GROUP_SEP && /[^\d]/gi.test(charStr)) { //Disable alpha input
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });

            //Increment buttons
            $scope.increment = function incrementMoney(increment) {
                if (!$scope.ngDisabled) {
                    $scope.ngModel = ($scope.ngModel || 0) + increment;
                }
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using more DOM interaction, like Shamal Perera suggested. Now it adds the number group separator as you write, keeping the cursor position:

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x8L74g75/4/)

```
$input.on('input blur keyup change', function contentEditableInput() {
                ngModel.$setViewValue($input.val());
            });
```

Comment: Thank you for this one but this doesn't support any value that contains decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Due to a problem in scope the formatter function is not called when text is typed. Therefore I changed the code to call a function on blur.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/uslperera/5nzux40p/116/)

### HTML

```
'<input type="tel" ng-model="ngModelCtrl.$viewValue" .. ng-blur="format()">'
```

### Script

```
$scope.format = function(){
    ngModel.$viewValue = numberFilter(ngModel.$modelValue);
};
```